# How to allow only one selection of checkboxes in kendo treeview / ui for jquery?

Tags: kendo-ui

I want to make checkbox mode single in kendo treeview / ui for jquery.

But there is no official option for jquery. I found solution to scan all treeview and uncheck others one by one. But it puts me in trouble because i have 3-4 depth and over +500 items in my treeview. When i select 2nd time, it takes around 1-2 seconds and freeze all treeview for a while.
This is a demo for dummy solution that i use. But it's not smooth for my actual treeview.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/treeview/index">
    <style>html { font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }</style>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.2.616/styles/kendo.default-v2.min.css" />

    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.2.616/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.2.616/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    
    

</head>
<body>
    <div id="example">
    <div class="demo-section wide k-content">
        <div id="demo-section-title" class="treeview-flex">
            <div>
                <h3>
                    Select nodes, folders and drag them between the TreeViews
                </h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="treeview-flex">
            <div id="treeview-kendo"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="treeview-flex">
            <div>
                <h4>Drag and Drop</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="treeview-flex">
            <div id="treeview-telerik"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script id="treeview" type="text/kendo-ui-template">

        # if (!item.items && item.spriteCssClass) { #
        #: item.text #
        <span class='k-icon k-i-close kendo-icon'></span>
        # } else if(!item.items && !item.spriteCssClass) { #
        <span class="k-sprite pdf"></span>
        #: item.text #
        <span class='k-icon k-i-close telerik-icon'></span>
        # } else if (item.items && item.spriteCssClass){ #
        #: item.text #
        # } else { #
        <span class="k-sprite folder"></span>
        #: item.text #
        # } #
    </script>

    <script>
        function traverse(nodes, callback) {
        for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
          var node = nodes[i];
          var children = node.hasChildren && node.children.data();
          
          callback(node);
          
          if (children) {
            traverse(children, callback);
          }
        }
      }
      
      function onCheck(e) {
        var dataItem = this.dataItem(e.node);

        var rootNodes = $("#treeview-kendo").getKendoTreeView().dataSource.data();

        traverse(rootNodes, function(node) {
          if (node != dataItem) {
            node.set("checked", false);
          }
        });
      }

$("#treeview-kendo").kendoTreeView({
            template: kendo.template($("#treeview").html()),
            dataSource: [{
                id: 1, text: "My Documents", expanded: true, spriteCssClass: "rootfolder", items: [
                    {
                        id: 2, text: "Kendo UI Project", expanded: true, spriteCssClass: "folder", items: [
                            { id: 3, text: "about.html", spriteCssClass: "html" },
                            { id: 4, text: "index.html", spriteCssClass: "html" },
                            { id: 5, text: "logo.png", spriteCssClass: "image" }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        id: 6, text: "Reports", expanded: true, spriteCssClass: "folder", items: [
                            { id: 7, text: "February.pdf", spriteCssClass: "pdf" },
                            { id: 8, text: "March.pdf", spriteCssClass: "pdf" },
                            { id: 9, text: "April.pdf", spriteCssClass: "pdf" }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }],
            //dragAndDrop: true,
            checkboxes: {
                checkChildren: true
                                
            },
                        check: onCheck,
            loadOnDemand: true
        });

        
       
    </script>
    <style>
        @media screen and (max-width: 680px) {
            .treeview-flex {
                flex: auto !important;
                width: 100%;
            }
        }

        #demo-section-title h3 {
            margin-bottom: 2em;
            text-align: center;
        }

        .treeview-flex h4 {
            color: #656565;
            margin-bottom: 1em;
            text-align: center;
        }

        #demo-section-title {
            width: 100%;
            flex: auto;
        }

        .treeview-flex {
            flex: 1;
            -ms-flex: 1 0 auto;
        }

        .k-treeview {
            max-width: 240px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

        #treeview-kendo .k-sprite {
            background-image: url("../content/web/treeview/coloricons-sprite.png");
        }

        #treeview-telerik .k-sprite {
            background-image: url("../content/web/treeview/coloricons-sprite.png");
        }

        .demo-section {
            margin-bottom: 5px;
            overflow: auto;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
        }

        .rootfolder {
            background-position: 0 0;
        }

        .folder {
            background-position: 0 -16px;
        }

        .pdf {
            background-position: 0 -32px;
        }

        .html {
            background-position: 0 -48px;
        }

        .image {
            background-position: 0 -64px;
        }

    </style>
</div>


    

</body>
</html>
```

There is an option mode:"single" for Angular.
[single mode checkbox for treeview in kendo ui for Angular](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/treeview/checkboxes/)

But i'm looking same kendo ui for Jquery.

Comment: You are passing the `function(node)` callback on every `traverse` invocation. Have you tried not passing it? Perhaps not passing it will make it a bit faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to manually traverse the nodes. You can leverage JQuery to get the appropriate selector and let it do it for you in the `check` event ([documentation](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/treeview/events/check)).

Basically what you'd do is:

1. Handle the `check` event
2. Get the inputs by selecting the treeview's `k-checkbox-wrapper` class' `input`
3. Set the `checked` property to false
4. Set the node that was checked back to true

Example:

```js
check: function(e) {
  $("#treeview .k-checkbox-wrapper input").prop("checked", false);
  $(e.node).find("input").prop("checked", true);
}
```

Fiddle: https://dojo.telerik.com/ALEJetoD

Comment: Did you try to check old ones? There's a bug on this fiddle. Check 3-4 times then check old ones again Then you'll see that what i mean.

Comment: @user3565914 - You're right. I've played around with it quite a bit and it appears that there is a bug with the checked event because it isn't firing consistently.

Answer (score 0):

```
check: function(e) {
  $("#treeview .k-checkbox-wrapper input").prop("checked", false).trigger("change");
  $(e.node).find("input").prop("checked", true);
}
```

Line 1: `$("#treeview .k-checkbox-wrapper input").prop("checked", false).trigger("change");`

- Deselect the all the checkbox from tree and trigger will update and manage the state of kendotree view.

Line 2 : `$(e.node).find("input").prop("checked", true);`

- Tree will check the selected node using prop.